# PhoneGap: some AJAX POSTs are never sent

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

My PhoneGap app is built with jQuery mobile and currently I'm testing on Android. Cross domain parameters in jqm are set and I use a wildcard for the phonegap "access"-origins. The app uses AJAX for some JSON-communication. Now all ajax GETs seem to work without a problem, but about 40% of the POSTs never reach my server (i.e. not even headers, logs show no signs of those posts). All the posts are very basic ajax calls to exactly the same address, with some minimal json-load, like an id and some short value. I am using the Chrome device inspect and can confirm the posts are looking consistent, but about 40% of those posts keep the status "pending" and will eventually timeout.

I've read something about caching, post-data is always unique, but I've added nocache-headers to the servers responses. Posts should never be cached imo, but this didn't help me anyway.

The bare jqm-app works fine in the browser. Embedded in phonegap, some posts fail.. does anybody have a clue?

Comment: show your code here please.

Comment: @Dato', it's a fairly big project. If you're wondering about my jquery ajax function: it's all the same function, the working calls and the not working calls. It has method set as post, a static url and a small object of length 2 as data, nothing complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've set up a second test project with only the functionality of sending ajax requests, both post and get, on short intervals (like 2s). Turned out that gets where getting timed out too and after a few iterations, everything just timed out.

Lately I've been experiencing Chrome-crashes while developing, so I set up my server to do some well-arranged logging. I didn't start the app from Eclipse this time, but disconnected my phone and started it manually on the phone itself. Guess what: everything just works fine, all ajax requests arrive at the server.

I had already tested without the Chrome DevTools device inspect, but with the phone connected to usb: didn't help. But Chrome crashing quite frequently still makes me suspect it has something to do with it while connected to the pc.

Update:
I ran into problems again when sending some larger requests, like images in base64. Now I set header "Connection: close" on my server and things seem smooth again, even with Chrome DevTools inspect, except for the crashing of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these options to your jQuery.ajax calls

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
cache: false
```

The first one allows cross domain posts and the second ensures that each request receives a unique parameter circumventing browser-side caching

Comment: Thanks, but this would require switching to the jsonp mechanisms and discarding current ajax communication. I would prefer finding a solution to fix current set-up.

Comment: did you try the cache:false option?

Comment: Yes I did, no success unfortunately

Comment: Did you look at the Network panel to see which network requests are actually being sent and which ones are not?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the opening post, all posts are sent, but some keep the status "pending". By the way, sometimes the first post (after launching) hangs and following posts just work, so I doubt it's a caching thing.

Comment: if you use `cordova serve`, does it also work properly?

Comment: No. I didn't know this command and can't find very extensive info about this. My terminal shows a bunch of loading assets with 200 response, then a "[console.log] no connection" and the browser is stuck at the loading gif. Terminal keeps posting "200 /__api__/autoreload"s and nothing happens. I suppose this should work normally, any directions for me to dig into?